# MySQL Rolling Count of Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to do a rolling count of registration growth on a student website.

The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(type) as student_count, MONTH(created_at) as month, YEAR(created_at) as year
FROM users
WHERE type = 'student'
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at), YEAR(created_at)
ORDER BY year, month
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve in the query is to keep adding up the `student_counts` from the previous rows.

So:

December 2014 should have 15 students

January 2015 should have 16 students

February 2015 should have 34 students

and so on...

Is this possible in SQL or is it better to do this when outputting the data in the code itself?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, @sum := @sum + student_count as sum
from
(
    SELECT YEAR(created_at) as year, 
           MONTH(created_at) as month, 
           COUNT(type) as student_count
    FROM users
    WHERE type = 'student'
    GROUP BY year, month
    ORDER BY year, month
) tmp
CROSS JOIN (select @sum := 0) s
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not sum up in the sum column. It just produces the same number as in the student_count column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using with rollup

```
SELECT COUNT(type) as student_count, MONTH(created_at) as month, YEAR(created_at) as year
FROM users
WHERE type = 'student'
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at) WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: This produces an error message: "Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY"

Comment: the ordering shoud not  need  using group by so .. answer  updated . just change the sequence of the column name in group for correct order by

Answer (score 0):

One approach to handle this in MySQL uses a correlated subquery to find the running total.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u2
     WHERE DATE_FORMAT(u2.created_at, '%Y-%m') <=
           DATE_FORMAT(u1.created_at, '%Y-%m')) AS student_count,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS ym
FROM users u1
WHERE type = 'student'
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m');
```

### Demo

Not much to explain here, except that `SELECT DISTINCT` gives us each unique year-month value in the table as a single record.  We then count all rows at that point in time or earlier to find the running total.

Comment: This produces error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month
FROM users u1
WHERE type = 'student'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,' at line 5"

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen Can you verify that my solution is/is not working for you?

Comment: The query seems to be running forever. Eventually had to stop it.

Comment: The table has 9475 records in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT @cumulative := 0;
SELECT @cumulative := @cumulative + student_count student_count,
       month, year
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(type) as student_count,
           MONTH(created_at) as month,
           YEAR(created_at) as year
    FROM users
    WHERE type = 'student'
    GROUP BY MONTH(created_at), YEAR(created_at)
) A ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: The student_count column is now just NULL for all rows.